# How do YOU implement a setup screen?

Tags: xcode, ipad

As per the tags indicate I'm developing in Xcode for the iPad.

So, I have a New Game setup screen that sits between my main menu screen and the actual game screen.  The new game setup screen is supposed to allow the user to customize their game by selecting the number of players, choosing an avatar for each and setting their names.  What I've done is I've setup the continue button to write all the settings to a appData.plist file before moving onto the actual game screen.  When the game screen appears (the viewDidLoad method) it reads from the plist to add the players to the table with their respective Avatars and so forth.

The question is, is this the right way to pass the data from a new game setup screen to the game screen? Should I use some method to gather the information from the screen and pass it along to the game screen without writting to some file?  I guess the ultimate question is how you're supposed to pass data from one view controller to another?  I'm using some plist file to write to and then read from when the board appears.  I get a sneaking suspicion that this is not the right way to do this.  However, I figure at some point I need to save this data to file anyway since I have to be able to restore the state of my app in the even that it gets closed or interrupted.  But what is YOUR preferred method to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just do what many console games, etc., do and create a save state for the new game automatically? Then you'd just save the state in the old view controller, and the loading would be the same for going from New Game to game screen as from main menu to game screen. (You might want to set up some settings to indicate first-time loading, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the built-in settings screen for your app by making use of the Settings.bundle too. This is very easy and allows you to use the default iPad settings screen for your application settings, rather than setting up a hand-made one.

For passing through information, the information I need is usually a single object (in your case maybe Player.m) and so I create a property in the next view to hold this. And before showing the view I then do (for instance):

```
GameViewController *gameView = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
gameView.player     = player;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameView animated:YES];
[gameView release];
```

Comment: okay, well that brings me to further expand on that.  Let's say that there can be between 2 and 6 players.  should a I create six separate player properties on my GameViewController? or should I use something like an NSMutableArray property in the GameViewController which would contain up to six player obects.  I guess on the awakeFromNib method I'd have to loop through the array and add the players to the table right?

Comment: It all depends on how you are storing your objects. You could for instance store everything into a sqlite database. Easy when using Data Core, and making your player object extend from NSManagedObject. That way you can just fetch all the objects (players) from the database in any screen you need them. Good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started